# .NET CsvReader Failing On Many Entries Maybe?

Tags: csvhelper

I'm trying to upload about 100 entries through my CsvHelper code it get to around 95 and give this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

if I split the csv into two it works fine, I have recently ensured every entry also works so the only thing I can think of is its too much for my code?

Code:

```
     var file = Request.Files["attachmentcsv"];
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file.InputStream), true))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
            csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Identifier>().ToList();
            foreach (var item in records)
            {
                var strip = item.domain.Replace("https://www.", "").Replace("http://www.", "")
                   .Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("www.", "");

                string[] URLtests =
                   {"http://www." + strip, "https://www." + strip, "https://" + strip, "http://" + strip};

                string[] Metric = MajesticFunctions.MajesticChecker(URLtests);

                if (Metric[1] == "Failed") { continue; }

                if (!(from c in db.Identifiers
                      select c.domain).Contains(Metric[0].Replace("/", "")))
                {
                    string name = "";
                    if (item.contactname != null && item.contactname.Length > 0) { name = item.contactname.First().ToString().ToUpper() + item.contactname.Substring(1);  }
                    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    var UserTableID = db.UserTables.Where(c => c.ApplicationUserId == userId).First().ID;

                    var identifier = new Identifier
                    {
                        domain = Metric[0].Replace("/",""),
                        contact = item.contact,
                        contactname = name,
                        price = item.price,
                        type = item.type,
                        TrustFlow = Int32.Parse(Metric[1]),
                        CitationFlow = Int32.Parse(Metric[2]),
                        RI = Int32.Parse(Metric[3]),
                        MJTopicsID = mjTopic,
                        UserTableID = UserTableID
                    };
                    ViewBag.identifier = identifier;
                    db.Identifiers.Add(identifier);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else { continue; }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

sample of csv:

```
domain,contact,contactname,price,type,MJTopicsID
bbmlive.com,info@bbmlive.com,,30,1,8
fluxmagazine.com,editorial@fluxmagazine.com,Lee,30,1,8
irishdogs.ie,Peter.Banks@irishdogs.ie,Peter Banks,15,1,5
roberthorne.co.uk,emily@sussexseo.net,Emily,30,1,12
```

can post stack trace if need be

Comment: It looks like the exception is coming from EF.

Comment: Is there an inner exception that gives more detail?